# 20px gap between collection view and its container

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicontainerview

I can see a 20px gap between collection view and its container and I do not know why. I set all constraints to stretch view the full container. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `UICollectionViewController` it is important to **set view's frame** after transition. In somehow `UITableViewController` set itself automatically.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let src = segue.sourceViewController as UIViewController
        let dst = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController

        addChildViewController(dst)
        view.addSubview(dst.view)
        dst.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        dst.view.frame = self.view.bounds //<-- this line is important for collection view
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps constraining to the margins? Dubbelclick your constraints and check if 'relative to margin' perhaps is checked (in the first/second item dropdowns). If so, uncheck it.

In the future you can prevent this by using the |-[]-| menu at the bottom and unchecking 'Constrain to margins' before adding the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little more explanation.

Comment: I had the same problem ,the solution  above it works for me, and thank you for your tips! @J.Chomel